# Generate gradient image texture on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, uiimage, metal, texture-mapping

I need to generate a 256x1 texture on iOS. I have 4 colors Red, Green, Yellow, Blue with Red on one end and Blue on the other, and Yellow and Green at 3/4th and 1/4th position respectively. The colors in between need to be linearly interpolated. I need to use this texture in Metal for lookup in shader code. What is the easiest way to generate this texture in code?

Comment: Do the colors or positions change? If not, why not just create an image and add it as an asset to your app bundle? If the colors do change, the easiest way (if you don't need custom interpolation in something like HSV space) is probably to create a `CGBitmapContext` and [draw a gradient](https://www.raywenderlich.com/410-core-graphics-tutorial-part-2-gradients-and-contexts) into it, then copy the resulting bytes into a `MTLTexture`.

Comment: Ok I created the image and also generated 256x1 texture. Problem is Metal is taking it as texture2d by default. How do I specify 1d texture while generating? Ofcourse I can use it as texture2d by specifying 0 in y coordinate, but still.

Answer (score 1):

Since `MTKTextureLoader` doesn't currently support the creation of 1D textures (this has been a feature request since at least 2016), you'll need to create your texture manually.

Assuming you already have your image loaded, you can ask it for its `CGImage`, then use this method to extract the pixel data and load it into a texture:

```
func texture1DForImage(_ cgImage: CGImage, device: MTLDevice) -> MTLTexture? {
    let width = cgImage.width
    let height = 0
    let bytesPerRow = width * 4 // RGBA, 8 bits per component

    let bitmapInfo: UInt32 = /* default byte order | */ CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!
    let context = CGContext(data: nil,
                            width: width,
                            height: height,
                            bitsPerComponent: 8,
                            bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                            space: colorSpace,
                            bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)!

    let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    context.draw(cgImage, in: bounds)

    guard let data = context.data?.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: bytesPerRow) else { return nil }

    let textureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(pixelFormat: .rgba8Unorm,
                                                                     width: width,
                                                                     height: height,
                                                                     mipmapped: false)
    textureDescriptor.textureType = .type1D
    textureDescriptor.usage = [ .shaderRead ]

    let texture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: textureDescriptor)!
    texture.replace(region: MTLRegionMake1D(0, width), mipmapLevel: 0, withBytes: data, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow)

    return texture
}
```